# Angular 7 Universal - Could not resolve paths

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular7, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I followed this great tutorial on serverside rendering with Angular Universal
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/

But when running `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`, I get the following errors:

[image: errors]

Somehow, it does not recognize the paths I defined in the `tsconfig.json` file.

`tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@auth/*": [
        "src/app/auth/*"
      ],
      "@core/*": [
        "src/app/core/*"
      ],
      "@entities/*": [
        "src/app/entities/*"
      ],
      "@shared/*": [
        "src/app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "src/environments/*"
      ],
      "@reducers/*": [
        "src/app/reducers/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide the relevant part in  tsconfig.json so we can try to find out what happened

Comment: sorry, I did now

Comment: Where in this tutorial does it say to write those paths in your tsconfig-file ?

Comment: It doesn't but my app relies on those path aliases (It makes importing a whole lot easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. My tsconfig.**server**.json had the parameter "baseUrl": ".". It overrides the tsconfig.json parameter "baseUrl": "./".  I just removed it and now works form me

tsconfig.**server**.json Before

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.**server**.json After

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```